# Alt+Tab+ Not Working in Vim

Tags: vim

I started using Vim on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

The keyboard is Danish and I can confirm that layout is Danish in Vim too.

However, I cannot create curly braces, `{`. Usually on a Danish keyboard they are created by pressing Alt+Tab+8.

Here is some observations

- I **can** create parenthesis, `(`, just fine with Tab + 8.
- I **cannot** create curly braces, `{`, with the usual Alt+Tab+8.
- I **cannot** create square braces, `[`, with the usual Alt+8.

It seems that something is "wrong" with the Alt key..

Here is my mappings:

```
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
   Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
   Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
v  <Right>     * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
v  <Left>      * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
v  <Down>      * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
v  <Up>        * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  <Right>     * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  <Left>      * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  <Down>      * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  <Up>        * <Nop>
   Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

I tried reinstalling `vim` with Homebrew

```
brew install vim                
alias vim=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1345/bin/vim
```

I tried resetting Mac OS keyboard preferences by Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys > Restore Defaults.

What can I do from here?

Comment: This is more likely a problem with your terminal emulator rather than vim. What are you using for that?

Comment: Good one! I see that I cannot use curly braces or square brackets in the terminal either. I am using Oh My Zsh.

Comment: Not the shell, the terminal emulator, they're different.  You will need to use `Ctrl+V` combinations and `xev` to get the keycodes. This is better asked on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). But seriously, remind me to never buy a Danish keyboard, both Alt and Tab keys are extremely hard to debug.  The former because it does not produce an escape code by itself by default, and the later because most programs do not understand combinations with Tab (it is not a modifier key by default).

Comment: I'm sorry, I was away for a few days. As grochmal said, I meant the application you used, like iTerm2. Anyway, you can debug what vim is "understanding" by pressing `Ctrl-v` in Insert mode and then try to insert a `{`. If it's iTerm there's a keyboard option to use left alt as meta, option or something else I don't remember. You could theoretically map whatever crap vim understands to what you want, but let's rule out it's not your terminal emulator changing alt for Esc.